HTML table with PowerShell
I have a script that takes bugs from TFS and builds a table with the relevant titles.
The script reads from XML 2 query IDs, creates 2 tables, and then sends them as an email.
The script is working but I need to add a space between the tables, currently, they stick together. I tried many things like br and div but nothing helped.
I will copy only the relevant code for the tables. I don't want to change the table or improve it, so help me to add a space between the tables
$HtmlTable = "<table border='1' align='Left' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0' style='color:black;font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;text-align:left;'>
                <tr style ='font-size:14px;font-weight: normal;background: #FFFFFF'>
                <th align=left><b>Version</b></th>
                <th align=left><b>Severity</b></th>
                <th align=left><b>Title</b></th>
                <th align=left><b>State</b></th>
                </tr>"
$HtmlTable += "<tr style='font-size:14px;background-color:#FFFFFF'>
    <td>" + $CloudVersion + "</td>
    <td>" + $Bug_Severity + "</td>
    <td>" + $Bug_Title + "</td>
    <td>" + $Bug_State + "</td>
    </tr>" 

$HtmlTable += "</table>"

All the above is a function that is called twice, $Htmls contains the 2 tables
$Htmls += $HtmlTable

This function displays the tables
function Print ($Htmls) {
    $outlook = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Outlook.Application')
    $Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
    foreach ($html in $Htmls) {
    $mail.HTMLBody += $html
    }
    $Mail.Display()
} 


Add margin around table to create some distance.

Can you write how to do it please?

Sure, just add this line  <table border='1' align='Left' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0' style='color:black;font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;text-align:left; margin: 15px'> & if only want css to add then add this margin: 15px to table.

As a general advise, try to avoid using the increase assignment operator (+=) to build a collection or string and use the PowerShell pipeline instead, something like: $mail.HTMLBody = $Htmls -Join '<br /><br /><br />'

margin-bottom: 20px; can only add space at bottom. also works well.

So to create space between the table you can use margin. In the below code I have add margin around the table.
You can copy below code and try it on your project, hope it helped thank you.


$HtmlTable = "<table border='1' align='Left' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0' style='color:black;font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;text-align:left; margin: 15px;'>
                <tr style ='font-size:14px;font-weight: normal;background: #FFFFFF'>
                <th align=left><b>Version</b></th>
                <th align=left><b>Severity</b></th>
                <th align=left style="min-width: 70vh;"><b>Title</b></th>
                <th align=left><b>State</b></th>
                </tr>"
$HtmlTable += "<tr style='font-size:14px;background-color:#FFFFFF'>
    <td>" + $CloudVersion + "</td>
    <td>" + $Bug_Severity + "</td>
    <td>" + $Bug_Title + "</td>
    <td>" + $Bug_State + "</td>
    </tr>" 

$HtmlTable += "</table>"




Thanks
I have one more issue, when one of the table is empty Ithe titles are being placed in the right instead of the bottom
I will add a screenshot

Hi @Meet
Can you see the new screenshot? when a table is empty the titles are in the right

Does anyone know how to do it?

@Bandit that happens because when there is no content in table 2 then its width gets decreased and due to that it moves to next of first div. We need to add flex properties to parent div.

Can you help with that? I really don’t know how to do it and where

@Bandit I have edited above response try it but I am not sure it would work or not.

This is the change?
min-width: 70vh

@Bandit yes, it is not preferred solution. Best and proper solution is to put both table inside a div and add display: flex & flex-direction: column. If its possible in your case then do prefer this solution.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

you could have some thing like this, wrap table to a flex div with spacing to
make it look neat.
$HtmlTable = "<div style="display: flex; padding: 1rem 0.5rem"> <table border='1' align='Left' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0' style='color:black;font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;text-align:left;'>
            <tr style ='font-size:14px;font-weight: normal;background: #FFFFFF'>
            <th align=left><b>Version</b></th>
            <th align=left><b>Severity</b></th>
            <th align=left><b>Title</b></th>
            <th align=left><b>State</b></th>
            </tr>"
$HtmlTable += "<tr style='font-size:14px;background-color:#FFFFFF'>
<td>" + $CloudVersion + "</td>
<td>" + $Bug_Severity + "</td>
<td>" + $Bug_Title + "</td>
<td>" + $Bug_State + "</td>
</tr>" 

$HtmlTable += "</table></div>"

please tell me if that worked or not.

Thanks but still do not  have space between the tables

the last function that you have  print where does it display the mail?

Screenshot added
